# Pointer and memory arithmetic in C

Tags: c

Taking the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main(void) {
    int *a = &(int) {4};
    ptrdiff_t b = (a+1) - a;
    int c = (char*) (a+1) - (char*) a; // actual memory difference
    printf("The first memory address is at: %p and the one after is: %p\n"
           "The difference with pointer arithmetic is: %td\n"
           "And actual difference in memory address is: %d\n",
        a, a+1, b, c);
}
```

> The first memory address is at: 0x7fff9cb3a1e0 and the one after is: 0x7fff9cb3a1e4 
> The difference with pointer arithmetic is: 1 
> And actual difference in memory address is: 4

Is this the proper way to do:

- ptr arithmetic: `ptrdiff_t b = (a+1) - a;`
- actual arithmetic between memory addresses: `(char*) (a+1) - (char*) a;`
- Formatters: `%td` for `ptrdiff_t`, and `%d` for actual memory difference (wouldn't this just be an int or is there a better formatter for this?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
int *a = &(int) {4};
```

`{4}` is a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal), its address can be taken just as you did.

---

```
ptrdiff_t b = (a+1) - a;
```

Pointer subtraction is well defined when the pointers involved point to elements of the same array, or the element past the last. Pointer `a` can point to an object or an array of objects. An object and array are different types, but a pointer doesn't distinguish the two, so that a scalar is treated as an array of 1 element. This code is well defined.

---

In

```
int c = (char*) (a+1) - (char*) a;
```

the type of difference is `ptrdiff_t`, which is `int` only on a 32-bit architecture.

Comment: thanks. What about the `void*` that the other answer mentions? What's wrong with just having `a` instead of `(void*) a` ?

Comment: @David542 `void*` is not required to have the same representation as `char*` or any other pointer, however, in early C days there was no `void*` and `char*` filled that role of the most generic pointer. Pedantically, you do need an explicit cast of any pointer to `void*` when passing it `printf` and friends. Practically, in architectures with flat memory model all pointers have the same size. Moreover, POSIX requires any pointer, such as object o function, to be convertible to `void*`.

Comment: ok, so would the more correct form be `int c = (char*) (a+1) - (char*) a;` or `int c = (void*) (a+1) - (void*) a;` ? -- both evaluate to 4 for me.

Comment: @David542 `void*` arithmetic is again not defined by C standard, but all compilers support that as an extension, which make `void*` arithmetic behave as that of `char*`. Another way is `intptr_t c = (intptr_t)(a+1) - (intptr_t)a;`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin In this statement `int *a = &(int) {4};`, this `(int) {4}` is a compound literal which results in an unnamed object initialised by initialiser list. Taking address of that unnamed object (i.e. `&(int) {4}`) is perfectly fine.

Comment: @H.S. You are quite right, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you take the difference of two pointers, the result has type `ptrdiff_t`.

So both `b` and `c` should be of this type, and `%td` is the format specifier you would use to print it.

Also, the `%p` format specifier expects a `void *` as a argument.  And since the implicit conversion to/from `void *` can't happens with variadic parameters, this is one of the few times an explicit cast to `void *` is required.

Comment: thanks, would it be `(void *)a+1` or `(void *)(a+1)` or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @David542 The former won't work because you can't do arithmetic on a `void *`.  So use the second one to send to `printf`.